# Union all on the same table need to show different data

Tags: mysql, union-all

I am working with `UNION ALL` on the same table to show different data with a conditional if the conditional is 1, but right now show me even if the conditional is 0.

Here is the mysql part:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("(SELECT  cod, CONCAT(name,' ',presentation) AS name, price, discount
        FROM PRODUCTS WHERE UPPER($type) LIKE :name GROUP BY cod)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT  cod, CONCAT(name,' ',presentation,'(box)') AS name, price1, discount1
        FROM PRODUCTS WHERE medida != '0' AND UPPER($type) LIKE :name GROUP BY cod)
        ");
```

I need show to the user two products only if the product searched have in `row 'medida'` the value `1`, if the `row 'medida'` in the product have the value `0` will only show one product
(some products sell per unit and  others products per units and in boxes)

Here is one capture where the item have value 0 in the row medida and is suppose to show only one item, the first one but show two items

[image]

Comment: what is medida for a type varchar text?

Comment: @nbk is type int

Comment: Could you please build a dbfiddle example of your problem and when you are add it, please change $type to :type and bind it afterwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the error, all is ok now, thank you @nbk for your help.

Here is the url to the dbfiddle to show the queries working

[UNION ALL same DB](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ptsuAiwvLWv1MqXhjFnYiX/2)